# How to use Ansible fact variable in role's variable file

Tags: ansible

I'm writing a role to configure shorewall on Linux server and I'd like to use `ansible_default_ipv4.interface` discovered variable inside role's `default/main.yml` file and then use via `template` module.

I have something like this now and it does not work:

```
linux_server_shorewall_interfaces:
  - { zone: net, iface: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}, options: "routefilter,tcpflags", comment: "net_<interface>" }
```

The error is:

```
   ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
     found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')

   The error appears to have been in '/tmp/kitchen/roles/linux_server/defaults/main.yml': line 59, column 26, but may
   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

   The offending line appears to be:

   linux_server_shorewall_interfaces:
     - { zone: net, iface: {{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}, options: "routefilter,tcpflags", comment: "net_<interface>" }
                     ^ here
   We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
   missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
   start a value. For instance:

       with_items:
         - {{ foo }}

   Should be written as:

       with_items:
         - "{{ foo }}"
```

I expect to see `net ens32 routefilter,tcpflags` in my file file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expansion of *{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}* [has to be quoted](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#hey-wait-a-yaml-gotcha) ([single-quotation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) is simpler). The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        linux_server_shorewall_interfaces:
          - { zone: 'net',
              iface: '{{ ansible_default_ipv4.interface }}',
              options: 'routefilter,tcpflags',
              comment: 'net_<interface>' }
    - debug:
        var: linux_server_shorewall_interfaces
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "linux_server_shorewall_interfaces": [
        {
            "comment": "net_<interface>", 
            "iface": "wlan0", 
            "options": "routefilter,tcpflags", 
            "zone": "net"
        }
    ]
}
```